# How to compare Time / Date on load

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a game in cocos2d. In this game there is an energy bar and this energy bar rejuvenates every 5 minutes. I want this rejuvenation to work across runs of the app.

I was thinking about it and all I could come up with was saving the date/time of the last termination of the app in NSUserDefaults and comparing it with the new date once re-opened and dividing that by the rejuvenation time and adding the correct amount of lapsed energy accumulated... however i don't know how to compare a string to a string + 10 hours or whatever my rejuvenation time is. Basically i want elapsed time to be tracked whether the app is open or closed.

Comment: Note that to prevent cheating by changing the time of the device to an earlier time, you should record the current time when your app is terminated. Next time it launches, compare the stored time with the current device time, and if the latter is earlier then you can be almost certain that the user was trying to cheat by resetting the clock. Almost because once a year there's daylight saving's time setting the clock back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly simple, you can obtain the current time (in milliseconds) from the epoch with:

```
NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

Store this value in your defaults. It's actually a `double`, so you can store it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:now forKey:@"lastClosed"];
```

Then you can get the time when the application relaunches using the above `NSDate` class method, and compare them as such:

```
NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval timeFromUserDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"lastClosed"];
int numSecondsPassed = (timeFromUserDefaults - now);
```

Comment: LearnCocos2D - Thanks for your reply, i wouldn't have thought about that if you didn't say anything cheers

Craig - Thanks to you too for your reply... to combat LearnCocos2Ds suggestion is there a global time in which we can base the above code off of instead of current phone time? would i have to setup a server and base the time off of that? any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Yea, you'll have to maintain a server to obtain a time that's not device-specific. In my opinion, unless this is a network/multiplayer game, if someone is willing to change their device time to get their HP back up, just let them. :)